# What is deg(xy=0)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Our professor in algebra geometry wrote us the following in class deg(xy=0)=2. I don't understand what that is, I know the definition of degree for the following let p be a polynomial deg(p)=max(sum of the exponents of the variables of each monomial).But in my case I don't have a polynomial I have the set of solutions of an equation, what is the definition of degree in that case?

Comment: This is a rather generalized notion of degree. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_an_algebraic_variety The fact is that the degree of a hypersurface $F = 0$ (in your case $xy=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^1$) is the *same* as the *total degree* of the *homogeneous polynomial* $F$ defining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Geometrically**, $xy=0$ corresponds to the union of the coordinate axes in $\mathbb A^2$. Now, you can define the **degree** of one-dimensional varieties as the number of intersections with a generic line in $\mathbb A^2$. If you intersect $xy=0$ with a generic line, then you get two intersection points, so the degree should be two.

(But beware, this is really kinda false: $\mathbb A^2$ is not compact, so intersection theory does not work nicely. In some sense, everything should have degree zero in $\mathbb A^2$, because you can "slide divisors away to infinity".)

**Algebraically**, the degree of any curve in $\mathbb A^2$ is the degree of its maximal term.

Comment: +1 It might be nice to explain that how to reconcile this max degree/homogenous degree and 'compactification' issue, is by moving to $\mathbb{P}^2$.